# how to create tags about a certain genre on a comic website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a few tags to filter categories in a comic web. Pls help me

[image]

Can just like this!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just like that tag

```css
span{
background:#444444;
color: #fff;
padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span>Tag</span>
<span>Tag</span>
<span>Tag</span>
<span>Tag</span>
```